# Retrieve Service Bus primaryConnectionString with az cli

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Is it possible to get Azure Service Bus primaryConnectionString with AZ CLI?

Input parameters:

1. Resource Group
2. Service Bus Name

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Years later it's now supported. In case anyone else stumbles upon this question like me, it can be done this way:

```
az servicebus namespace authorization-rule keys list --resource-group myresourcegroup --namespace-name mynamespace --name RootManageSharedAccessKey --query primaryConnectionString -o tsv
```

Answer (score 2):

For now, Azure CLI 2.0 does not support service bus. You could use `az -h` to check. Power Shell and Azure CLI 1.0(asm mode) support service bus now.

You could use Power Shell to get primary ConnectionString.

```
$CurrentRule = Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceAuthorizationRule -ResourceGroup $ResGrpName -NamespaceName $Namespace -AuthorizationRuleName $AuthRule
$AuthRule=$CurrentRule.Name
(Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey -ResourceGroup shuibus -NamespaceName shuitest -AuthorizationRuleName $AuthRule).PrimaryConnectionString
```

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-manage-with-ps).

Update:

On a Linux VM, you could use [this Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/namespaces#Namespaces_ListKeys) to automation generate connectionstring.

```
POST /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{namespaceName}/AuthorizationRules/{authorizationRuleName}/listKeys?api-version=2015-08-01
```

Comment: Thanks. But I try to automate deployment scripts under linux. How to invoke Power Shell script with linux enviroment?

Comment: @popalka For now, it is not possible.

Comment: @popalka On Linux, you could use Rest API to get ConnectionString. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/namespaces#Namespaces_ListKeys

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: @popalka You need create a service principle firstly. I test successful with `Invoke-RestMethod`. Now, I use `curl` for test, I will give you the result.

Comment: @popalka The default `authorizationRuleName` name is `RootManageSharedAccessKey`

Comment: I didn't try yet. I stopped at creating service principle step.  I'll try to keep this thread up-to date, thanks

Comment: OK, if you any question about this. Please post here.

Comment: As of October 2023, Shui's answer for REST API requires a tweak. The api version should be 2022-10-01-preview. So the full request URL becomes [ https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionguid}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{serviceBusNamespace}/AuthorizationRules/RootManageSharedAccessKey/listKeys?api-version=2022-10-01-preview ]